# Objective-C - why the UITapGestureRecognizer crashing the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

I have dynamic UIView as Array droplet. When clicked on those random UIView object, i need to do activity on that specific droplet. So when i trigger this `UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ui_view_array_clicked)];
    [ui_view addGestureRecognizer:gesRecognizer];` the app crashing.

What might be going wrong? i tried also `@selector(ui_view_array_clicked:i)` but crash in both case as soon as i click any of those UIView which is attached with the `gesRecognizer`

[image: enter code here]

**ERROR:**

```
2017-03-14 02:16:33.322 testing[80405:5647302] -[ViewController ui_view_array_clicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9733d01f70
2017-03-14 02:16:33.337 testing[80405:5647302] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController ui_view_array_clicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9733d01f70'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc85d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f6e721e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fcf5f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0b005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0ab88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001105e5409 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001105ed1a8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001105eac77 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 227
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001105e9f03 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 891
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001105d5f7e _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1395
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001105d59c3 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001105d4ba6 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011011ac1d -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001100c79ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001108b472d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001108ad463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc2a761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0f98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0ee76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0e884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113a71a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001100a9c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  testing                             0x000000010f11053f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112ae768d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**CODE:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *randomSelection;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger phone_height;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger phone_width;
-(void)ui_view_array_clicked:(int)array_id;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)ui_button_submit:(UIButton*)sender {
  int phone_height  =  self.view.frame.size.height;
  int phone_width  =  self.view.frame.size.width;
  self.phone_height = phone_height;
  self.phone_width = phone_width;

  NSMutableArray *randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  // Set - UIView
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int l = 0;
  for (int i = 0;  i <= 50; i++) {
    int col = floor(self.phone_width/50);
    int logic = floor(i/col);

    int xx = (i * 50);
    if (logic == 1) {
      xx = (j * 50);
      j++;
    }
    else if (logic == 2 ) {
      xx = (k * 50);
      k++;
    }
    else if (logic == 3 ) {
      xx = (l * 50);
      l++;
    }


    NSLog(@">>> %d %d %d %d" , xx ,  logic  ,  i, j);
    UIView *ui_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xx, 50 * logic , 50,50)];
    [randomSelection addObject:ui_view];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ui_view_array_clicked)];
    [ui_view addGestureRecognizer:gesRecognizer];


    if(i%2==0) {
      ui_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else {
      ui_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:ui_view];

  }

  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Made 50 RED UIView"
                                                                 message:@"Will make them Black now" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
      NSLog(@"<<< %d" , i);
      UIView *test = [randomSelection objectAtIndex:i];
        //test.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      if(i%2==0) {
        test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      }
      else {
        test.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      }

    }
  }];
  [alert addAction:defaultAction];
  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)ui_view_array_clicked:(int)array_id {
  NSLog(@">>> clicking: %d", array_id);

}

-(void)ui_button {
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  UIButton *but = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  [but setTitle:@"--- Add ---" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [but setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [but addTarget:self action:@selector(ui_button_submit:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  int startHeight = 167;
  int frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - startHeight;
  [but setFrame:CGRectMake(0, startHeight, 320, frameHeight)];

  [but setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
  [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:but];


  NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"button" : but};
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-0-|"
                           options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

  NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:but
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
      toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0
      constant:0];
  constraint.active = true;
  [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self ui_button];
}


@end
```

Comment: Isn't it a case where the colon is missing is the selector statement?  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ui_view_array_clicked:)]; ?  Also, -(void)ui_view_array_clicked:(int)array_id { doesn't look good.

Comment: Correction: missing is the selector statement => missing in the selector statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action method for your gesture recognizer is

`ui_view_array_clicked`

But you don't have a corresponding method in the view controller.

You *do* have

```
-(void)ui_view_array_clicked:(int)array_id
```

But this is a different method / signature.

In addition

- the signture for a gestureRecognizer target takes either no parameters or a single paramenter. The parameter for the single-parameter version is required to be of a specifc type: namely, the gesture recognizer sending the message.

So either of the following patterns works:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
              initWithTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(gestureSelector)];  
 //selector

- (void)gestureSelector
```

or...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
              initWithTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(gestureSelector:)];  
 //selector

- (void)gestureSelector:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
```

*Also*...

using `snake_case` is highly un-idomatic for ObjectiveC ... `camelCaseAtAllTimes` is recommended, especially for methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should change init method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ui_view_array_clicked:)];
```

And the function should declare as

```
- (void) ui_view_array_clicked: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below answer

```
UIView *ui_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xx, 50 * logic , 50,50)];
[randomSelection addObject:ui_view];
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ui_view_array_clicked:)];
[ui_view addGestureRecognizer:gesRecognizer];
```

This will set the tap gesture on your `view`

To access the tapped `view` inside your method

```
- (void)gestureSelector:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    UIView *your_tapped_view = gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```

Use this code.

Don't forget to add `:` in your gesture method declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the remark `UIView *your_tapped_view = gestureRecognizer.view;`